# How to configure Mule CE to send HTTP request through corporate proxy?

Tags: esb, mule

I am learning Mule ESB CE. I am trying the very first example, the *Google Spell Checker*. Everything seems to be OK, except that the HTTP request cannot go through the corporate proxy (or so I think). I get this error:

```
Exception stack is:
1. connect timed out (java.net.SocketTimeoutException)
  java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl:-2 (null)
2. The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 10000 ms (org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException)
  org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory:155 (null)
3. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://www.google.com:80/tbproxy/spell?lang=en, connector=HttpConnector
```

The proxy settings in Mule Studio seems to be OK, it used the Windows 7 proxy settings; I can try to run an update or install new software, it can connect to the Mule website. O get proper message (an error, but it's expected) when I access the Google spell checker URL from browser.

I did not see a way to configure the proxy in the HTTP endpoint settings.

So, the only thing I can suspect is the proxy settings of the Mule engine. Am I correct assuming this? If yes, how can I set the proxy? If not, what do I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy parameters are configured on the **http:connector** element as shown in the [HTTP transport configuration reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-ConfigurationReference).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to create an **http:connector**, but it seems that I cannot do it a drag'n'drop way; I needed to edit the XML file directly. When I switched back to the visual representation, the **http:connector** appeared as grey square with question mark. And when I tried to execute the flow, it failed and complained that invalid content was found and it expected something else. I put the **http:connector** after the **http:outbound-endpoint**. How should I use the **http:connector**? Thanks again.

Comment: Just place the http:connector as a direct child of the mule configuration root node. I usually put my connectors above my global endpoints and flows. Regarding Studio handling of this particular element: I do not know, I edit my Mule configs with an XML editor :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked like charm. I found how to add the **http:connector** visually: there is a _Global Elements_ tab in the editor. Editing XML directly is a nice, brave act; I am not yet licensed to do it. :-)

Comment: what is the api url  SOAP and REST for using in mule service to implement a spell checker/corrector.